# $push is not working with MongoDB(Add the answer to the questions answer array) how do i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

> 

This is the answer.action.ts code:

```
"use server";
import Answer from "@/database/answer.model";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../mongoose";
import { CreateAnswerParams, GetAnswersParams } from "./shared.types";
import Question from "@/database/question.model";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function createAnswer(params: CreateAnswerParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();
    const { content, author, question, path } = params;
    const newAnswer = await Answer.create({
      content,
      author,
      question,
    });

    // Add the answer to the questions answer array
    const updateQuestion = await Question.findByIdAndUpdate(
      question,
      {
        $push: { answers: newAnswer._id },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    console.log("add answer to Question:::", updateQuestion);

    // Todo: add interaction...

    revalidatePath(path);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
export async function getAnswers(params: GetAnswersParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();
    const { questionId } = params;

    const answers = await Answer.find({ question: questionId })
      .populate("author", "_id clerkId name picture")
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    return { answers };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

im trying to Add the answer to the questions answer array but there is no error and updateQuestion log is returning null, so $push is not working and answer object in mongodb database is empty and i try chatgpt and check _id and it was match and Question model schema is correct and also the Answer model schema is correct so i dont know what is the problem

Comment: What is the content of question? Is it an ObjectId? Does it already exist? Or should you enable `upsert`? Since updateQuestion this needs to be resolved first.

Comment: In Nextjs everything is by default server side rendered, so you don't need to explicitly use "user server".